How to fix: near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
today , i have met a error about heap memory of javascript. I don't know why my code used much memory.

const listSocialMedia = '.ec_details_social_icon';
const inforOfItem = '#ec_product_image_effect_4481370';


class changeDirectionItem {
    
    // choice Item to see infromation
    async clickChoiceItem() {
        await $(inforOfItem).click();
        await browser.pause(3000);
    }

    // Change direction of item
    async changeDirection() {
        for ( socialMedia of Array.from($$(listSocialMedia)) ) {

            // change direction of item
            await socialMedia.click();

            // wait for 3 seconds
            await browser.pause(4000);

            // back to navigation item
            await browser.back();
        }
    }
}

module.exports = new changeDirectionItem();



this is error:
[0-0] <--- JS stacktrace --->
[0-0]
[0-0] FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
[0-0]  1: 00007FF756023CEF node::SetCppgcReference+15695
[0-0]  2: 00007FF755F9E606 EVP_MD_meth_get_input_blocksize+78566
[0-0]  3: 00007FF755FA03F1 EVP_MD_meth_get_input_blocksize+86225
[0-0]  4: 00007FF756A0A191 v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+65
[0-0]  5: 00007FF7569F3928 v8::Function::Experimental_IsNopFunction+1336
[0-0]  6: 00007FF756855190 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+659552
[0-0]  7: 00007FF756861413 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+709347
[0-0]  8: 00007FF75685ED74 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+699460
[0-0]  9: 00007FF756851EB0 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+646528
[0-0] 10: 00007FF75686752A v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+734202
[0-0] 11: 00007FF756867DA7 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+736375
[0-0] 12: 00007FF7568766CF v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+796063
[0-0] 13: 00007FF756536C95 v8::CodeEvent::GetFunctionName+116773
[0-0] 14: 00007FF756ABAD3E v8::PropertyDescriptor::writable+674542
[0-0] 15: 00007FF756A64596 v8::PropertyDescriptor::writable+320326
[0-0] 16: 00007FF6D6DF1E65
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - file:///D:/PVD_HOCTAP/Back%20End/Javascript/Automated_Testing_demo/test/Function_Test/Test_Mini/Change_Direction_Item.js

I hope you will help me tell me where this error started and how to solve this problem.
my version of nodeJs 20.8.0
thank you so much
